# How do I override DisplayFor boolean?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, boolean, checkbox, display-templates

How do i create a display template so i can display a bool as Yes or No not a checkbox? Using mvc3

```
<%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SomeBoolean)%>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had to create something similar so it would display "Sim" and "Não" (portuguese Yes/No).  I created the following file:

```
 Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\Boolean.ascx
```

And added the following code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<%= (bool) ViewData.Model ? "Sim" : "Não" %>
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**
Forgot, in your view, simply call it like so:

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Ativo) %>
```

**EDIT 2**
For a nullable (bool?), try this:

```
<%= (ViewData.Model == null) ? "NA" : (ViewData.Model == true) ? "Y" : "N"%>
```

**EDIT 3**
Using Razor syntax (Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\Boolean.cshtml):

```
 @{ Layout = null; }
 @(ViewData.Model ? "Sim" : "Não")
```

Comment: I had to add a cast to a boolean like this:   

    `<%= (bool) ViewData.Model ? "Yes" : "No" %>`

Thanks, this worked great!

Comment: Just a suggestion: try to avoid nullable booleans. Many times bool? = false is, for the application, the same as bool = false. 

Also, many times the end user cannot distinguish between a null value and a false one (for the boolean datatype). Essentially, if you're using checkboxes to control your booleans, skip the null. If you need the tri-state (null, true, false) you'll be using some sort of dropdown or a fancy checkbox that specifically indicates the absence of a value!

Comment: I'm struggling to convert this to Razor syntax.  Can anybody help?

Comment: Agree with @TiagoMatias, don't see a case for nullable checkboxes.

Comment: Short and sweet, that worked for me! Thanks @mateuscb

Answer (score 14):

How about just this simple thing:

```
@((bool)item.Ativo ? "Yes" : "No")
```

Answer (score 7):

you can extend HtmlHelper for bool.

and remember you must use direction YesNoExtensions namespace on razor page .
rem:we can overload DisplayFor for boolean with change function sign.

```
public namespace SampleExtensions
{
    public static class YesNoExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString DisplayFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, bool flag = true)
        {
            object o = expression.Compile().Invoke(html.ViewData.Model);
            if (o.GetType() == typeof(bool))
            {
                if ((bool)o)
                    return new MvcHtmlString("Yes");
                else
                    return new MvcHtmlString("No");
            }
            return DisplayFor(html, expression);
        }
    }
}
```

and razor page.

```
<%@ import namespace='SampleExtensions' %>


<%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SomeBoolean, true)%>
```

last parameter true is dummy for select right DisplayFor which has been overload by us. I hope usefull.

Comment: can i not create a new display template under shared and pass in a string value?

Comment: yes, you can do it. remember, to give template name for DisplayFor. it will work.

Answer (score 6):

`@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.SomeBoolean)`.

Use the in-built Display**Text**For() instead on DisplayFor().

This is an old post, but I was having trouble finding a current answer.

Answer (score 0):

For true/false use [DisplayTextFor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29382101/1452172) by Justin Grant

For yup/nope based on [Nuri YILMAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871044/1452172), this is .NetCore 2.2, to downgrade replace HtmlString with MvcHtmlString:

1) C# write new extension DisplayForYZ

```
public namespace X.Views.Shared
{
    public static class DisplayExtensions
    {
        // If this was called DisplayFor not DisplayForYZ, we'd get recursion
        public static IHtmlContent DisplayForYZ<TModel, TValue>
          (this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression) 
        where TModel : Y
        {
            object o = expression.Compile().Invoke(html.ViewData.Model);
            // For any bool on TModel, return in this custom way:
            if (o.GetType() == typeof(bool))
            {
                return (bool)o ? new HtmlString("Yup") : new HtmlString("Nope");
            }
            // Otherwise use default behaviour 
            return html.DisplayFor(expression);
        }
    }
}
```

2) cshtml: Import the `DisplayExtensions` namespace and use new extension.

```
@model X.ViewModels.Y
@using X.Views.Shared;

@Html.DisplayForYZ(modelItem => modelItem.Z)   @*//Yup/Nope*@
@Html.DisplayForYZ(modelItem => modelItem.A)   @*//default non bool behavior*@

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Z)     @*//check box*@
@Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => modelItem.Z) @*//true/false*@
```

**X** = {my company}
**Y** = {object for customised display} **Z**= {bool property} **A**= {non-bool property}