# Changing Html.DisplayFor bool? text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a situations when I trying to display bool? value.
In case if my bool doesn't exist:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.HasType)
```

Shows text "Not set".
By itself it is fine, but I need show another text.
How can I replace "Not set", for example with "Empty"?

I could just do something like:

```
@if (!Model.HasType.HasValue)
{
   ...
}
else
{
   ...
}
```

But I want to know, is there a possibility to change "Not set" itself.

P.S Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: you can use **Template** see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6878320/1849444)

Comment: Yes just looked at the source code and you cannot override the "Not Set" used by the default template. You will need to create your own template as @teovankot says.