# C# MVC Razor Display total hours of a Timespan

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, timespan

I have a Razor view with

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalTime)
```

and the type of TotalTime is TimeSpan.

It works great problem is we have now found a few cases where the TotalTime goes over 24hrs so it shows as 1.01:00:00 (1day, 1Hr, 00Mins, 00 Secs). so the value is still correct but I need it to display as 25:00:00 (25Hrs, 00Mins, 00Secs).

I could change the model to a string but it's used in various places including formulas etc so it's not a simple task, hence I am looking to just change the display of the value.

I have looked around for a Data Annotation for the DisplayFor but not found one that will work so I am open to suggestions

Thanks

Cliff.

Comment: Similar situation for a Boolean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870683/how-do-i-override-displayfor-boolean

Comment: Have you tried the [TotalHours](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute `item.TotalTime.TotalHours`?

Comment: And the `DisplayFor` helper is trying to be "helpful" and producing that formatted string. You'll need to write your own or not use it at all.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to take the separate parts calculate the hours from the Days and Hours parts.

Here's a helper extension:

```
public static HtmlString TimeSpanString(this HtmlHelper helper, TimeSpan val)
{
    double days = val.Days;
    double hours = val.Hours + (days * 24);
    double minutes = val.Minutes;
    double seconds = val.Seconds;
    var formattedString = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", hours, minutes, seconds);

    return new HtmlString("<span>" + formattedString + "</span>");
}
```

Usage:

```
@Html.TimeSpanString(item.TotalTime)
```

Comment: Jasen Thanks for the helper but I didn't need it as the code I posted worked great and gave me what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so as suggested by Jim Crandell above I have added a Display Template like so:

```
Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\TimeSpan.cshtml (I created a new folder and a partial view)
```

Inside this new partial view I added:

```
@model TimeSpan
@string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}",(Model.Days *24) + Model.Hours, Model.Minutes, Model.Seconds)
```

And it works Yay thanks guys...